# Prestashop Hook for refunds

Tags: prestashop, hook

does anybody know if there is a hook in Prestashop for (partial) refund in the backoffice? I have already tried "actionOrderReturn" but it doesn't seem to work...

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Can you please provide any code sample you have tried please and any error logs.

Answer (score -1):

Here is the list of hooks available in Prestashop. [Hooks](https://devdocs.prestashop.com/1.7/modules/concepts/hooks/list-of-hooks/)

First, you need to make a simple module and in that module, you need to register hook ***actionOrderReturn*** in this module and you can add a function named ***hookActionOrderReturn($orderReturn)***